# how to read a particular string from a buffer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, buffer

i have a buffer

```
char buffer[size];
```

which i am using to store the file contents of a stream(suppose pStream here)

```
HRESULT hr = pStream->Read(buffer, size, &cbRead );
```

now i have all the contents of this stream in buffer which is of size(suppose size here). now i know that i have two strings

```
"<!doctortype html" and ".html>"
```

which are present somewhere (we don't their loctions) inside the stored contents of this buffer and i want to store just the contents of the buffer from the location

```
"<!doctortype html" to another string ".html>"
```

in to another buffer2[SizeWeDontKnow] yet.

How to do that ??? (actually contents from these two location are the contents of a html file and i want to store the contents of only html file present in this buffer). any ideas how to do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strnstr function to find the right position in your buffer. After you've found the starting and ending tag, you can extract the text inbetween using strncpy, or use it in place if the performance is an issue.
You can calculate needed size from the positions of the tags and the length of the first tag 
 `nLength = nPosEnd - nPosStart - nStartTagLength`

Comment: does visual c++ supports strnstr function if you any idea ??? and what is nStartTagLength ? as i uderstand you nLength is the size of the total html contents and nPosStart="<!doctortype html"  and nPosEnd= ".html>" we just need this why you have used nStartTagLength
 ???

Comment: visual c++ does not have strnstr, but if you are not sure that the Read-function is giving you an zero-terminated string, you can put the terminal zero in it yourself:
`char buffer[size+1];
ZeroMemory(buffer,size+1);`

nPosStart and nPosEnd are the positions of start tag "<!doctortype html" and end tag ".html>". nStartTagLength is the length of "<!doctortype html". I am sorry, but what you are asking are the basic algorithms and its scope is beyond this forum.

Comment: so do you know equivalent function for visual c++ ?? and do you think that i canaccompish it by using strtok() here??  -      while (pch != NULL)
  {
        pch = strtok (NULL, "!doctortype html"  
  return 0;
} can i get the position of "!doctortype html" using this ?

Comment: You can use strstr if the buffer is zero-terminated. If it is not, you can make it zero-terminated, like I explained in my previous comment.

Comment: if i do like this then strstr gives error C2665: 'strstr' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: Lookup the c++ reference for [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/). It does not take the size parameter like the strnstr does. Please do learn the tools before using them.

Answer (score 0):

Look for HTML parsers for C/C++.

Another way is to have a char pointer from the start of the buffer and then check each char there after. See if it follows your requirement.

Comment: i am intersted in the second idea but could you please tell me that by doing character pointer from start i can compare just have one character at a time but i have to compare a full string which is of the size equal to the size of **"<!doctortype html"**(not character) by doing so thats the problem.. have you understood what i mean to say ?

Comment: `&buffer` is the pointer to your buffer area. Now create another char pointer as `char *b = &buffer`. Now b is pointing to the start of buffer and you can move this around and not lose your buffer.

Now, if the first character in your buffer is '<', then `*b` is '<'. Keep incrementing b and you can read one char at a time. Now keep comparing to the string you want, and you have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you limited to C, or can you use C++?

In the C library reference there are plenty of useful ways of tokenising strings and comparing for matches  (string.h):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/

Using C++ I would do the following (using buffer and size variables from your code):

```
    // copy char array to std::string
    std::string text(buffer, buffer + size);

    // define what we're looking for
    std::string begin_text("<!doctortype html");
    std::string end_text(".html>");

    // find the start and end of the text we need to extract
    size_t begin_pos = text.find(begin_text) + begin_text.length();
    size_t end_pos = text.find(end_text);

    // create a substring from the positions
    std::string extract = text.substr(begin_pos,end_pos);

    // test that we got the extract
    std::cout << extract << std::endl;
```

If you need C string compatibility you can use:

```
char* tmp =  extract.c_str();
```

Comment: i am using visual c++. do you think that strtok is good for me because i have to search the location of "<!doctortype html" and ".html>" and then store the contents between them . what do you suggest ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a C++ example that I've tested using g++ compiler: g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3). Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Glad you've got an answer, Many Thanks, Simon.

Comment: if you want to see you can go this link i have written the solution to find the file containing a particular file ".html" inside a buffer/stream http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920081/how-to-skip-a-file-inside-the-tar-file-to-get-a-particular-file/17928714#17928714  it may be useful for you in future

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only operation which operates on HTML code in your app, then you could use the solution I provided below (you can also test it online - [here](http://ideone.com/ZgwLtE)). However, if you are going to do some more complicated parsing, then I suggest using some external library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* beforePrefix = "asdfasdfasdfasdf";
    const char* prefix = "<!doctortype html";
    const char* suffix = ".html>";
    const char* postSuffix = "asdasdasd";

    unsigned size = 1024;
    char buf[size];
    sprintf(buf, "%s%sTHE STRING YOU WANT TO GET%s%s", beforePrefix, prefix, suffix, postSuffix);

    cout << "Before: " << buf << endl;

    const char* firstOccurenceOfPrefixPtr = strstr(buf, prefix);
    const char* firstOccurenceOfSuffixPtr = strstr(buf, suffix);

    if (firstOccurenceOfPrefixPtr && firstOccurenceOfSuffixPtr)
    {
        unsigned textLen = (unsigned)(firstOccurenceOfSuffixPtr - firstOccurenceOfPrefixPtr - strlen(prefix));
        char newBuf[size];
        strncpy(newBuf, firstOccurenceOfPrefixPtr + strlen(prefix), textLen);
        newBuf[textLen] = 0;

        cout << "After: " << newBuf << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
I get it now :). You should use `strstr` to find the first occurence of the `prefix` then. I edited the code above, and updated the [link](http://ideone.com/ZgwLtE).

Comment: without knowing the location of prefix  and suffix  i can't get the data between them so  "THE STRING YOU WANT TO GET" is not possible i think you still couldn't understand my question.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I've missed this detail. I've just updated the answer :)

Comment: so do you have any idea of getting the location in visual c++ ?? in cwe can do using strnstr but not here..any ideas ??

Comment: The code is still the same. yourTextLen should be calculated like this:
`int nPosStart = strstr(buf,prefix) - buf; 
int nPosEnd = strstr(buf,suffix) - buf; 
int yourTextLen = nPosEnd - nPosStart - strlen(prefix);`

Comment: Thanks. In the previous edit, I updated only the link, now the code is updated too.

Comment: Length calculation is still wrong. You should use the positions found using strstr, instead the lengths.

Comment: if i use strstr then it gives error C2665: 'strstr' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types (no instance of overloaded function ""strstr matches the argument list )

Comment: @BojanHrnkas: thanks man, the answer is corrected one more time :).